# Remove entire parent XML in Notepad++ when specific child is not present

Tags: notepad++, regex, xml

I have several large XML files that contain the following:

```
      <TERM>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <TERM_CODE>1</TERM_CODE>
        <ALTERNATIVE_REPORT_CARD_FLAG>F</ALTERNATIVE_REPORT_CARD_FLAG>
        <DAYS_ABSENT>3</DAYS_ABSENT>
        <TIMES_LATE>2</TIMES_LATE>
      </TERM>
```

But also contains similar blocks, such as:

```
      <TERM>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <TERM_CODE>2</TERM_CODE>
        <ALTERNATIVE_REPORT_CARD_FLAG>F</ALTERNATIVE_REPORT_CARD_FLAG>
        <DAYS_ABSENT>12</DAYS_ABSENT>
        <TIMES_LATE>0</TIMES_LATE>
        <SUBJECT_STRAND>
          <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
          <SUBJECT_STRAND_CODE>ART-20</SUBJECT_STRAND_CODE>
        </SUBJECT_STRAND>
        <LEARNING_SKILL>
          <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
          <LEARNING_SKILL_CODE>CL</LEARNING_SKILL_CODE>
          <LEVEL>ES</LEVEL>
        </LEARNING_SKILL>
      </TERM>
```

I would like to remove all the blocks that don't contain the `<SUBJECT_STRAND>`  child.

Using the S/R function in Notepad++ this seems to work when I only have one of each of the blocks above in a file, but fails when there are several instances of both:

```
<TERM>.*?</TIMES_LATE>\R[^<SUBJECT_STRAND>]+</TERM>\R
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<TERM>(?:(?!<SUBJECT_STRAND>).)*?</TERM>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<TERM>                  # literally
                    # Tempered Greedy Token:
  (?:                   # start non capture group
    (?!                 # start negative lookahead, make sure we haven't:
      <SUBJECT_STRAND>  # literally
    )                   # end lookahead
    .                   # any character
  )*?                   # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
</TERM>                 # literally
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]